# Connecting data from Big Query to Cloud Fucntion to perfrom NLP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, nlp

I wish to perform sentimental analysis using **Google Natural Language API**.

I found a documentation that perform sentiment analysis directly on a file located in Cloud Storage, https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/analyzing-sentiment#language-sentiment-string-python.

However, my data that i am working on is **instead located in Big Query**. I am wondering how do I **call the data directly from Big Query table** to do the Sentimental Analysis?

An example of the Big Query Table schema:
[image]

I wish to do NLP on the **tweet** columns of the table.

I tried to search for documentation on it but seems to not find anything.

I would appreciate any help or references. Thank You.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, consider upvoting and accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [BigQuery Remote Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/remote-functions) which provide a direct integration with Cloud Functions and Cloud Run. The columns returned from BigQuery SQL can be [passed](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/remote-functions#json_encoding_of_sql_data_type) to the Remote Functions and a custom code can be executed as per the requirements. Please do note that Remote Functions are still in preview and might not be suitable for production systems.

Comment: That's the correct pattern, and exactly the reason of that new feature!

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly straightforward to do with Dataflow - you could write a pipeline that [reads from BigQuery](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#reading-from-bigquery) followed by a [DoFn](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo) that uses [Google's NLP Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/sentiment-analysis-client-libraries), and then [writes the results to BigQuery](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#writing-to-bigquery).

Some wrappers are already provided for you in https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/ml/gcp/naturallanguageml.py